# Run external vba-code in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

Can I link in external code to a Word document?
I have a lot of word documents with macros (VBA-code). All with the same code. I would like the code to be run from an external source instead of from within all of those documents. That way, if I have to update the code, I only have one place where I have to do the update.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a template and put it in the %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP folder, this makes the template an addin and STARTUP is a trusted location which will give you fewer security issues than using macros in templates from other locations.

Then, any document can call a function in the template using Application.Run().

e.g.

In your template write following:

```
Function templateHello() As String
    templateHello = "hello from template!"
End Function
```

Then, in any Word document you can write:

```
MsgBox Application.Run("templateHello")
```

Which will display a message box with "hello from template!"

Answer (score 2):

Move the code to the **attached template**, then the macros are available in all documents based on that template.

Comment: Thaks for the answer! Is that the only way to do it? We´re in a platform where we sometimes experience problems when we use other teplates than normal.dot.

Comment: If you want to use VBA code, that's about it. You could convert the code to a word Plug in (VB6 or any .net lang can do that), but that might be beyond what you're really needing.