# Centralized VBA code for multiple Word files

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have multiple files with the same VBA code in them, which will most likely have to be changed over time. I don't want to go one by one and c/p the code, so one obvious idea that came to mind is to have one centralized document with the code (template?) that all files refer to.

I found a few topics here at stackoverflow, but none of them work for me or are inconclusive:

[Run external vba-code in MS Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923778/run-external-vba-code-in-ms-word)

[Centralized VBA code (one file) for multiple workbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28631897/centralized-vba-code-one-file-for-multiple-workbooks)

[Calling an External VBA from VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192618/calling-an-external-vba-from-vbscript)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your idea of centralizing the code in a template and attaching that template to the various Word docs will work. These pics are using Word 2007 but I think it's pretty similar for newer versions. First create a new document and put the code in a Module (named "CommonFunctions" in the picture):

[image]

Save the doc as a macro-enabled template:

[image]

Now make a new document, save it as a *.docm (necessary for it to run code because a *.docx is macro-free), and attach the document template as shown below. (An alternative is to put the *.dotm file in the startup directory `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP`, which loads it automatically.) If you don't put it in the Startup, you'll see the name but it won't be loaded (ie, checked), but you can load it in code, as I'll show.

[image]

Make a user form in this document:

[image]

Put this code for the button's click event:

```
If AddIns("c:\_b\MasterDocWithFunctions.dotm").Installed = False Then
    AddIns("c:\_b\MasterDocWithFunctions.dotm").Installed = True
End If

Application.Run "CommonFunctions.Test1"
Application.Run "CommonFunctions.Test2"
```

[image]

Notice how the code can load the AddIn for you, because it won't be automatically loaded unless you put it in the Startup directory. This pic shows how the AddIn is referenced but not loaded. You need the checkbox to be able to call code in it. If you don't load it using code and don't put it in the Startup, then the user will have to manually put a checkmark everytime the document opens.

[image]

Now the form should work when you click the button. Notice how it can call both public and private functions. The Private keyword definitely shields one module from another, but it seems like modules that are called from an AddIn are considered to be part of the same module, not sure why? Also if you don't put Public or Private at all then VBA considers it Public, I'm pretty sure.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, but I think it doesn't work in my case... All my buttons and radio button macros stopped working. Is there something I need to do a little differently in this case?

Comment: So you put the code and forms in a *.dotm file, is that right? What about if you open the *.dotm file directly? Do the buttons work from it? Just trying to see if the *.dotm file is broken, or if something is breaking when the *.dotm file is attached to a new document and used.

Comment: Nope, not working in the dotm either. I cut and pasted all the code from "ThisDocument" to "Module1", if that matters. I don't think copy paste is the right way to go, because it should only remain in the module, correct?

Comment: I also just noticed that I can however run all the non private macros from the Macros window like you displayed in the screenshot. Just none of the form elements seem to be triggering anything automatically.

Comment: So the modules and form are all replicated verbatim among the various word docs? What about if you take one of those Word docs and do a Save As to an *.dotm file? In theory the form should still work right because it's an identical copy of the word doc. If it doesn't, maybe the security settings are blocking the code. These are under Orb>Word Options>Trust Center>Trust Center Settings>Macro Settings. Do the form elements make calls to other files by path, or perhaps to a database?

Comment: The form in the template stops working once I move everything to the module, so it all breaks there already. Maybe because most of the codes are  "private" subs? Maybe that's the key to the problem? I turned of the security and that didn't help either. Also, no, it isn't pointing to anything external.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand better now. I rewrote the answer. Let me know if this helps.